# Combining two parts of different strings

Tags: javascript

am working on a masking field that needs to pre-populate data. I have both sets of data, but don't want to show users the entire number.

I have two bits of information that I need to combine together, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
Str1 = XXXXX-XXXXX-XX00
Str2 = 12345-12345-1234
```

I need to combine these strings so that the user only sees `XXXXX-XXXXX-XX34.`
The pattern (Str1) can be changed so it is not a set in stone pattern which is what is making this difficult.

Is there a way to combine those?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is called a mask. Searching for "javascript apply mask to string" returns quite a lot of apparently good results.

Comment: Moreover, a naive implementation could be done as follow : for each character of the mask, if the character is the "mask" character, output the "mask" character ; else, output the character at the same index in the other string.

Comment: @Aaron I have a mask that is being applied when typing, however it is not being applied if there is data already there. Hense why I am trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Aaron I am doing that when typing, but this is when data is already there the mask does not know what to do with it.

Comment: Well, apply the mask to the data as described above before it is used to prepopulate fields? Reusing the existing mask code would obviously be better, but you didn't provide it and it's hard to guess if that would be feasible

Comment: You could trigger a `keypress` or `keyup` or `blur` event, if typing in is automatically updating the mask.

Comment: @sabithpocker I already have masking code that does that. I was looking for something that applies it when it first loads.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use use split to make yours strings become arrays and map to filter the final array and finaly join to obtain a String like this :

```
var  Str1 = "XXXXX-XXXXX-XX00"
var Str2 = "12345-12345-1234"
var result = Str1.split("").map((x, index) => x==='0' ? Str2.split("")[index] : x).join("");
console.log(result); //XXXXX-XXXXX-XX34
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simplistic approach

```js
var a = "XXXXX-XXXXX-XX00";
var b = "12345-12345-1234";
var result = "";
if (a.length !== b.length) throw "Strings must be same length.";
for (let i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++) {
  switch (a[i]) {
    case '0':
      result += b[i];
      break;
    default:
      result += a[i];
  }
}
console.log(result);
```